# Can a function with variable no. of arguments be overloaded in VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have an exported function in a dll(written in vc++) which has got variable no. of arguments. Now I want to overload this function without variable no. of arguments. Is there anything wrong with this concept? The reason I am concerned is because I have read that vc++ uses __cdecl calling convention for c and c++.

Sample signatures are given below.

```
void f(int i, char *fmt, ...);
void f(int i, string str);
```

Comment: If your DLL only uses a C interface, then you cannot overload functions. If you make a C++ library, you potentially constrain yourself to using it only with the same compiler.

Comment: For extra fun, you can mix the C and C++ functions in a single DLL. Then you can use the C function from any compiler, and the C++ overloads from the original compiler, but be careful when writing the header file.

Answer (score 0):

It depends from where are you planning to call these functions.
They should be converted to names like `f__FiPc??` and `f__Fi6string`.

C++ compiler will decode them and C compiler will miss the function `f` if you haven't declared `extern "c"`. However it depends on the implementation of your compiler.